# progress flickers in powershell python

Tags: python, powershell

The progress bar flickers in my Powershell and I wanted to ask for some advice.

```py
from progress.bar import IncrementalBar

i = 0
j = 100

bar = IncrementalBar('Progress', max = j, suffix='%(eta)ds')

while i <= j:
    i += 1
    bar.next()
```

I'm using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/progress).

Comment: Yes, it flickers if you call it ridiculously fast.  So, don't do that.  Progress bars are useful when a task takes a long time, and there you won't notice the flicker.

Comment: Ah okay. But is that the case for every progress bar? Or is there something that I can do against it? Edit: in reference to my code, because I have an original code, where I have to count till 10^8 and more

Comment: Interesting.  I just fetched your code to try it.  As written, it's all done in a blink, so there's nothing to see.  So, I added `time.sleep(0.05)` to the loop.  With cmd on Win 10, there is no flicker at all.  With PowerShell, I get a flicker about half the time.  I have no explanation for that.  The code should not flicker; they're not erasing the line before drawing.  This has to be some issue with PowerShell and the graphics card.